# Hive query throwing error "java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException"

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am trying to execute following hive query on Amazon EMR 5.8 with Hive 2.3.0

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS base_session (
property_num string,
visitId string,
fullVisitorId string,
adate string,
sessionStartTime timestamp,
totalVisits int,
totalHits int,
totalPageViews int,
totalTimeOnSite int,
totalBounces int,
totalNewVisits int,
totalScreenViews INT,
totalUniqueScreenViews int,
totalTimeOnScreen int,
browser string,
browserVersion string,
os string,
osVer String,
screenColors string,
screenResolution string,
deviceCategory string,
geoNetworkCountry string,
geoNetworkRegion string,
orgId int,
userType string,
landingScreen string,
exitScreen string,
org_session_num int,
geoNetworkMetro string,
deviceMobileBranding string,
start_business_context string,
end_business_context string,
totalViews int,
hits_appinfo_id STRING,
hits_appinfo_name STRING,
hits_appinfo_version STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION '${BUCKET}/base/session/';


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bt_session (
property_num string,
visitId string,
fullVisitorId string,
adate string,
sessionStartTime int,
totalVisits int,
totalHits int,
totalPageViews int,
totalTimeOnSite int,
totalBounces int,
totalNewVisits int,
totalScreenViews INT,
totalUniqueScreenViews int,
totalTimeOnScreen int,
browser string,
browserVersion string,
os string,
osVer String,
screenColors string,
screenResolution string,
deviceCategory string,
geoNetworkCountry string,
geoNetworkRegion string,
geoNetworkMetro string,
deviceMobileBranding string,
totalViews int,
hits_appinfo_id STRING,
hits_appinfo_name STRING,
hits_appinfo_version STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION '${BUCKET}/temp/bt/session/';






CREATE TABLE temp_session_orgid as
SELECT
    sorgid.property_num, sorgid.visitid, sorgid.fullvisitorid, sorgid.adate, sorgid.hits_customvariables_customvarvalue as orgid
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            row_number() over (partition by property_num, visitid, fullvisitorid, adate order by hitsid) as rn
        FROM bt_hits_custom_vars
        WHERE hits_customvariables_customvarname = 'orgId'
    ) sorgid
WHERE
    sorgid.rn = 1
;

CREATE TABLE temp_session_userType as
SELECT
    sut.property_num, sut.visitid, sut.fullvisitorid, sut.adate, sut.hits_customvariables_customvarvalue as userType
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            row_number() over (partition by property_num, visitid, fullvisitorid, adate order by hitsid) as rn
        FROM bt_hits_custom_vars
        WHERE hits_customvariables_customvarname = 'userType'
    ) sut
WHERE
    sut.rn = 1
;




CREATE TABLE temp_session_hitdata as
SELECT DISTINCT
sh.property_num, sh.visitid, sh.fullvisitorid, sh.adate,
sh2.business_context as start_business_context,
sh2.appinfo_exitscreenname as exitscreen,
sh2.appinfo_landingscreenname as landingscreen,
sh3.business_context as end_business_context
FROM
(
    SELECT property_num, visitid, fullvisitorid, adate,
    min(hitid) over (partition by property_num, visitid, fullvisitorid, adate ) as first_id,
    max(hitid) over (partition by property_num, visitid, fullvisitorid, adate ) as last_id
    FROM bt_hits
) sh
left join bt_hits as sh2
    on (sh.property_num = sh2.property_num
        and sh.visitid = sh2.visitid
        and sh.fullvisitorid = sh2.fullvisitorid
        and sh.adate = sh2.adate
        and sh.first_id = sh2.hitid)
left join bt_hits as sh3
    on (sh.property_num = sh3.property_num
        and sh.visitid = sh3.visitid
        and sh.fullvisitorid = sh3.fullvisitorid
        and sh.adate = sh3.adate
        and sh.last_id = sh3.hitid)
;

create table bt_session2 as
select
    s.*, O.orgid, U.userType, sh.landingscreen, sh.exitscreen, sh.start_business_context, sh.end_business_context
from
    bt_session s
    left join temp_session_orgid O
        on (O.property_num = s.property_num and O.visitid = s.visitid and O.fullvisitorid = s.fullvisitorid and O.adate = s.adate)
    left join temp_session_userType U
        on (U.property_num = s.property_num and U.visitid = s.visitid and U.fullvisitorid = s.fullvisitorid and U.adate = s.adate)
    left join temp_session_hitdata sh
        on (sh.property_num = s.property_num and sh.visitid = s.visitid and sh.fullvisitorid = s.fullvisitorid and sh.adate = s.adate)
;

INSERT INTO TABLE base_session
select
    property_num,
    visitId,
    fullVisitorId,
    adate,
    from_unixtime(sessionStartTime) as sessionStartTime,
    totalVisits,
    totalHits,
    totalPageViews,
    totalTimeOnSite,
    totalBounces,
    totalNewVisits,
    totalScreenViews,
    totalUniqueScreenViews,
    totalTimeOnScreen,
    browser,
    browserVersion,
    os,
    osVer,
    screenColors,
    screenResolution,
    deviceCategory,
    geoNetworkCountry,
    geoNetworkRegion,
    orgId,
    userType,
    landingScreen,
    exitScreen,
    if( orgid is not null,
        row_number() over (partition by property_num, visitid, adate, orgid order by sessionstarttime),
        null) as org_session_num,
    geoNetworkMetro,
    deviceMobileBranding,
    start_business_context,
    end_business_context,
    totalViews,
    hits_appinfo_id,
    hits_appinfo_name,
    hits_appinfo_version
from
    bt_session2
;
```

When I am executing this query,I am getting following exception :

```
    Vertex failed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1504998200702_0026_1_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1504998200702_0026_1_01_000023, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Container container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061 finished with diagnostics set to [Container failed, exitCode=-104. Container [pid=17003,containerID=container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 3.2 GB of 7.5 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
    Dump of the process-tree for container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061 :
        |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
        |- 17003 17000 17003 17003 (bash) 0 0 115810304 679 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk/bin/java -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN  -Dlog4j.configuratorClass=org.apache.tez.common.TezLog4jConfigurator -Dlog4j.configuration=tez-container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1504998200702_0026/container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061 -Dtez.root.logger=INFO,CLA  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx1229m -Dlog4j.configuratorClass=org.apache.tez.common.TezLog4jConfigurator -Dlog4j.configuration=tez-container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1504998200702_0026/container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061 -Dtez.root.logger=INFO,CLA  -Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1504998200702_0026/container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061/tmp org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezChild ip-10-212-196-172.johndeerecloud.com 41390 container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061 application_1504998200702_0026 1 1>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1504998200702_0026/container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061/stdout 2>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1504998200702_0026/container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061/stderr  
        |- 17016 17003 17003 17003 (java) 6237 246 3331600384 393016 /usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk/bin/java -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Dlog4j.configuratorClass=org.apache.tez.common.TezLog4jConfigurator -Dlog4j.configuration=tez-container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1504998200702_0026/container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061 -Dtez.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx1229m -Dlog4j.configuratorClass=org.apache.tez.common.TezLog4jConfigurator -Dlog4j.configuration=tez-container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1504998200702_0026/container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061 -Dtez.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1504998200702_0026/container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061/tmp org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezChild ip-10-212-196-172.johndeerecloud.com 41390 container_1504998200702_0026_01_000061 application_1504998200702_0026 1 

    Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
    ]], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1504998200702_0026_1_01_000023_1:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":"89634781","reducesinkkey1":"1412865647","reducesinkkey2":"4585400128498998895","reducesinkkey3":"20141009","reducesinkkey4":"1"},"value":{"_col1":"5268"}}
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":"89634781","reducesinkkey1":"1498837079","reducesinkkey2":"4333289744492811332","reducesinkkey3":"20170630","reducesinkkey4":"1"},"value":{"_col1":"CUSTOMER"}}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.run(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
    ... 14 more
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":"89634781","reducesinkkey1":"1498837079","reducesinkkey2":"4333289744492811332","reducesinkkey3":"20170630","reducesinkkey4":"1"},"value":{"_col1":"CUSTOMER"}}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:287)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator.process(FilterOperator.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator$PTFInvocation.handleOutputRows(PTFOperator.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator$PTFInvocation.processRow(PTFOperator.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator.process(PTFOperator.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:356)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.checkClosed(DFSOutputStream.java:1546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write(FSOutputSummer.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:60)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat$1.write(HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:762)
```

I even tried setting this config for hive shell:
hive> set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false;
hive> set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled=false;

but still this fails. 
Sometime this query runs successfully while sometime it fails due to above reason.Is there any other workaround for resolving this?

Comment: There is no `ClosedChannelExcetion` visible here.

Comment: @EJP: I have updated the logs

Comment: @Akki, I am also facing similar issue in one the HQL query. We are using EMR v5.11.1 and Hive 2.1.1. Are you able to resolve this issue?